# Selenium en OWin Selfhost - how to debug?

Tags: c#, selenium, owin

I want to create a Selenium Webdriver test and for this to work, I want to start the existing OWin application using OWin SelfHost.

For some reason, the OWin server does not respond once a breakpoint is it... Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Below is the code with some more info...

```
    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void InitDriverAndBackend()
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://127.0.0.1:9001/";
        httpServer = WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: baseAddress);
        Thread.Sleep(30000);
        //I have a breakpoint on the line below. Before the breakpoint is hit, 
        //I receive a response when going one of my webapi's on port 9001
        //However, once the breakpoint is hit, the server does not response at all and the request stays pending
        Driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
```

So, I expect to receive a response but once a breakpoint is hit, the requests just stay pending.

Answer (score 0):

Your tests and your OWIN app are separate things. Don't mix them. You shouldn't run UI tests as you would do to unit tests - creating a mocked instance and testing it.

**Compile your OWIN app. Deploy it. Run it. Then start your tests from a separate process against the deployed app. Optionally, stop the server after tests finished.**
This is a part of what is called proper CI/CD process.

---

OK, now to your question: what happens is that this `Driver = new ChromeDriver();` is non-blocking. So the method finishes, the garbage collector cleans up, and this effectively means the death of your OWIN app.

*OK, that was simplified version. In the case of a breakpoint you described, the entire application is stopped, so it simply cannot process your response.*

This is wrong, but should you really really need to do it within the same application:

1. inherit all test classes from some base
2. in that base in [OneTimeSetup] (nUnit) or equivalent method, create on a separate thread the owin server which won't stop until explicitly told so `(while(!ready2Exit){Thread.Sleep(100);})`
3. in [OneTimeTearDown] set that `ready2Exit` to `true`;

But mind you, this is marginally wrong.

Comment: Hi Mike, in my continuous deployment pipeline, I'd like to run my webdriver/selenium tests before actual deploying it. 

I don't follow why after the `new ChromeDriver();` my OWin process would get garbage collected. I keep a reference to the HttpServer which is a IDisposable which I dispose at the end of all tests in a `[OneTimeTearDown]` method.

I'll try your idea about starting it in another thread (or Topshelf?) - I'm curious! 
Thanks for the help

Comment: OK, if your server is only disposed in TearDown, it's not getting garbage-collected. Then it's the second, italics portion of the answer: once the application reaches the breakpoint, it's completely frozen, so the Owin app simply doesn't answer.